# Contents of array incorrect

Tags: php, sql

I currently have this SQL statement:

```
SELECT p.*,k.name FROM posts AS p 
    LEFT JOIN `post-keywords` AS pk ON p.id = pk.id_post 
    LEFT JOIN keywords AS k ON pk.id_keyword = p.id
    ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT :num,:count
```

however, it doesn't work as expected. This is what the server returns:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["title"]=>
    string(28) "Everything about Internet"
    ["text"]=>
    string(41) "Article itself"
    ["date"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["name"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["title"]=>
    string(16) "Internet"
    ["text"]=>
    string(32) "Text text text"
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "1371186330"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "tag1"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["title"]=>
    string(16) "Internet"
    ["text"]=>
    string(32) "Text text text"
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "1371186330"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "tag2"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["title"]=>
    string(16) "Internet"
    ["text"]=>
    string(32) "Text text text"
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "1371186330"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "tag3"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["title"]=>
    string(16) "Internet"
    ["text"]=>
    string(32) "Text text text"
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "1371186330"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "tag4"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["title"]=>
    string(16) "Internet"
    ["text"]=>
    string(32) "Text text text"
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "1371186330"
    ["name"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [6]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["title"]=>
    string(16) "Internet"
    ["text"]=>
    string(32) "Text text text"
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "1371186330"
    ["name"]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

How to retrieve an array from the server that contains multiple `name` fields:

```
array (5) {
   ["id"] =>
   string (1) "1"
   ["title"] =>
   string (16) "Internet"
   ["text"] =>
   string (32) "text text text"
   ["date"] =>
   string (10) "1371186330"
   ["name"] =>
   string (10) "word1"
   ["name"] =>
   string (10) "word2"
   ["name"] =>
   string (10) "word3"
}
```

Comment: What is `vozvraŝal` and `Tegami`?

Comment: There can't be multiple entries with same **key** in a hash, hence the last one takes precendence... (eg if you have "name" column in multiple tables, you will only get one key in the hash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your query is 'overwriting' fields that have multiple entries with the same name. For example, you are getting `p.name` and `k.name`. You query doesn't make a difference, so it gets overwritten to (I presume) `k.name`.

To make sure you get them both, write something like: `SELECT p.name AS p_name, k.name AS k_name`